# Android: How to show data from another ArrayList on OnItemLongClick in List

Tags: android

First time poster, short time android coder (for fun) and learned a lot from StackOverflow when I ran into problems. This time, however, I can not find a solution for my problem and hope someone can help me.

What I'm trying to do is this (and please keep in mind that I probably don't know the right lingo...):

- Get data for a ListView from a MySQL search via PHP.
- The retrieved data (per item "date" and "date_id") is put in two arrays (Date & _ids2).
- The ListView is populated with the response in array Date.
- Then when I longpress an item in the List I want it to display the associated date in _ids2 array containing the "date_id" (I'm trying to do this to check if I can get this data for a pop-up menu I'm planning)
- This is where it goes wrong -> app crashes :(

Thx in advance for your notes!!

This is the code to load the listview (I put the data in different arraylists):

```
private void loadIntoListView(String url) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                if(jsonObject.getInt("success")==1){
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String date=jsonObject1.getString("date");
                        String date_id = jsonObject1.getString("date_id");
                        Date.add(date);
                        _ids2.add(date_id);
                    }
                }
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(CheckInputThisActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Date));
            }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This is in the oncreate (when longpressing it does work when I'm trying to get the data from the getSelectedItemPosition):

```
loadIntoListView(data_url);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            date_id = _ids2.get(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            //String date =  listView.getItemAtPosition(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), date_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the complete code of the activity:

```
package com.merman.factuurinput;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.merman.factuurinput_test.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CheckInputThisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_MONTH = "month";
    private static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";
    private String date;
    private String date_id;
    private String month;
    private String monthcurrentset;
    private String year;
    private SessionHandler session;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> Date;
    ArrayList<String> _ids2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkinputthis);

        //Create Url
            session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());
            User user = session.getUserDetails();
            Boss boss = session.getBossDetails();
            Dateset dateset = session.getDateDetails();
            String data_url="http://192.168.1.123/myfactuur/check_input.php?month=" + dateset.getMonth() + "&year=" + dateset.getYear() + "&userid=" + user.getUserID() + "&boss=" + boss.getBossID();

        Date=new ArrayList<>();
        _ids2=new ArrayList<>();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        TextView bossText = findViewById(R.id.bossText);
        bossText.setText("Gewerkt voor " + boss.getBossName());

        //Create Month from Monthnumber
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");

            String monthnum = dateset.getMonth();

            /* converting the string to an int value
             * ,the value of inum2 would be 123 after
             * conversion
             */
            int monthnum2 = Integer.parseInt(monthnum);
            int inum = -1;
            int sum = inum+monthnum2;

            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,sum);
            String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());

            TextView monthText = findViewById(R.id.monthText);

            monthText.setText("Maand "+ month_name +" " + dateset.getYear());

        Button backBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        Button previousmonthBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousmonth);
        Button nextmonthBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnNextmonth);

        //Change Input to Next Month when Button is clicked
        nextmonthBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(CheckInputThisActivity.this, CheckInputThisActivity.class);

                //create month +1
                Dateset dateset = session.getDateDetails();
                monthcurrentset = dateset.getMonth();
                int inum = +1;

                int monthcurrentsetint = Integer.parseInt(monthcurrentset);

                int sum = inum+monthcurrentsetint;

                month = String.valueOf(sum);
                year = dateset.getYear();

                setdatedetails();
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //Change Input to Previous Month when Button is clicked
        previousmonthBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(CheckInputThisActivity.this, CheckInputThisActivity.class);

                //create month -1
                Dateset dateset = session.getDateDetails();
                monthcurrentset = dateset.getMonth();
                int inum = -1;

                int monthcurrentsetint = Integer.parseInt(monthcurrentset);

                int sum = inum+monthcurrentsetint;

                month = String.valueOf(sum);
                year = dateset.getYear();

                setdatedetails();
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //Launch CheckInputActivity screen when Back Button is clicked
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(CheckInputThisActivity.this, CheckInputActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        loadIntoListView(data_url);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                date_id = _ids2.get(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                //String date =  listView.getItemAtPosition(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), date_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jsonObject.getInt("success")==1){
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String date=jsonObject1.getString("date");
                            String date_id = jsonObject1.getString("date_id");
                            Date.add(date);
                            _ids2.add(date_id);
                        }
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(CheckInputThisActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Date));
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void setdatedetails() {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //Populate the request parameters
            request.put(KEY_MONTH, month);
            request.put(KEY_YEAR, year);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.setDateDetails(month,year);
    }
}
```

Logcat reader:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.merman.factuurinput_test, PID: 19404
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
at com.merman.factuurinput.CheckInputThisActivity$4.onItemLongClick(CheckInputThisActivity.java:153)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:4356)
at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:4254)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Comment: Hello, can you please post the crash log. Thanks.

Comment: yeah please post it, because it may be a ArrayOutOfBounds

Comment: Thx for the fast response, where do I find the crash log? :|

Comment: On your left-bottom there is someting called Run.. if you are connected with a USB cable to your computer so you will see everything your program is doing.. when appear red messages thats the error.. also can appear on Logcat

Comment: Never got the USB connection to work, cpu not compatible I think.. is there another way? From the device itself.

Comment: Ok, I found something, installed logcat reader on phone and got an error message after going through the long log :-) I'll update my post

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and start the debugger.... Maybe is a good situation to learn about a very useful tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that those arrays do not have the same length (or you might try to access index `-1`). Better fix your USB debugging bridge in the first place ...or use the Android emulator for debugging, which works without an USB cable.

The actual problem with `.getSelectedItemPosition()` is, that there is nothing selected:

```
public static final int INVALID_POSITION

Represents an invalid position. All valid positions are in the
range 0 to 1 less than the number of items in the current adapter.

Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)
```

---

And there is even an index and an ID being passed into the listener, so it should be:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        date_id = _ids2.get(position);
        ...
        // or even:
        date_id = id;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved it! Gonna read more, too much copy/pasting isn't the right way..

Comment: @LoLig01 learning how to [debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) suggested; this often explains more than any documentation.